# Custom python editor

Tags: python, editor

I am looking for such python editors which suggest inputs(mentioned in file/database) while using custom modules and functions during writing programs.

Is there similar type of editor already exists that I can build something upon?
Can I develop such editor? If yes, how?

Comment: Have you tried [spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_(software))?

Answer (score 1):

Try PyCharm, probably this software will cover all your needs

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, that you use the PyDev plugin for eclipse. PyDev has a lot of stuff, that increases the efficiency. You find it under: http://www.pydev.org/

Best Regards
1574ad6

Comment: I have already tried PyDev but can it be used to sync with database?

Comment: Code usaually is in a file or a repository like subversion, github, team foundation server, ... Files, and code repositories are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vim editor by including this line in your ~/.vimrc file.

```
:h ins-completion
```

Now you can use the below keyboard shortcut for auto complete feature for your custom functions.

Completion can be done for:

1. Whole lines                                          |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-L|
2. keywords in the current file                         |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N|
3. keywords in 'dictionary'                             |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K|
4. keywords in 'thesaurus', thesaurus-style             |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-T|
5. keywords in the current and included files           |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-I|
6. tags                                                 |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-]|
7. file names                                           |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F|
8. definitions or macros                                |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-D|
9. Vim command-line                                     |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-V|

if you want to learn the vim basics use this link :[Vim Basics](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Tutorial)

You can use this .vimrc file for python development :

```
set title
autocmd FileType python set expandtab ts=4 sw=4

"autocmd FileType python set sw=4
"autocmd FileType python set sts=4
"autocmd FileType python set ts=4
" enable syntax highlighting
"autocmd FileType python syntax enable
" show line numbers
" set numbe

" set tabs to have 4 spaces
" autocmd FileType python set ts=4

" indent when moving to the next line while writing code
"set autoindent

" expand tabs into spaces
"autocmd FileType python set expandtab

" when using the >> or << commands, shift lines by 4 spaces
"autocmd FileType python set shiftwidth=4

" show a visual line under the cursor's current line
" set cursorline

" show the matching part of the pair for [] {} and ()
set showmatch

" enable all Python syntax highlighting features
autocmd FileType python let python_highlight_all = 1

" to change the default colour of the string to white.
highlight String guifg=1 guibg=11
:h ins-completion
```

Comment: why have you downvoted?? It works very well, moreover the full version of pycharm is not free and also it's not an editor its and IDE.

Comment: Thanks @KevinAartsen